# I want to to load javascript based add-in on click on the button in toolbar via macro can anyone tell me how to do that process?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-addins, word-addins, ribbonx

I have an add-in and I have created a toolbar for office word.
I have used the office ribbon editor to design a custom UI for the toolbar and when I click on the button inside the toolbar I want to load the add-in.

so can anyone guide me to archive this functionality
thanks in advance.

Comment: Office hasn't used toolbars for over 15 years. You should be using an installer to install the add-in. In your scenario, you would need an add-in installed (or at least a macro-enabled document or template open) to create the button that would install the add-in.

Comment: @JohnKorchok web add-ins don't have installers.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, the O.P. has not posted whether they are using VBA, COM or Office.js for their add-in. The original post had only a VBA tag, so assuming there is an installer makes sense in that context.

Comment: @JohnKorchok yeah, it is not clear what technology exactly the author is going to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a supported scenario. Web add-ins don't provide any API for that.

Feel free to post a feature request/suggestion to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform .